# jquery plugins and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jquery to write plugins to my application.
Each plugin requires different css file.
What is the best method to load both the jquery file and the css?

I  am using the plugins in different pages under different locations. How can I find out the absolute path to those files?

EDIT: Does anyone has an answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

I think the fairly standard way is just to require than whenever a plugin is used, it's corresponding CSS file is used too.

You could have your jQuery plugin do this though:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/myPlugin.css" />');
```

Or even:

```
if (!$('head>link[href$="myPlugin.css"]').size()) // if the stylesheet isn't already included
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/myPlugin.css" />');
```

Better yet, put that in its own plugin:

```
$.extend({addStyleSheet : function (nameOfPlugin) {
    if (!$('head>link[href$="' + nameOfPlugin + '.css"]').size()) // if the stylesheet isn't already included
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/' + nameOfPlugin + '.css" />');
});
```

Then in your plugin, just call it like this:

```
$.addStyleSheet('myPlugin');
```

Comment: I prefer not to put the path of the css in the plugin. I cannot use in the plugin: href="/css/myPlugin.css" because the plugin doesn't suppose to know what is the site directory structure.

Comment: Well if you prefer not to have to include the CSS explicitly, but you also prefer not to have the plugin do it, you have no other option. You'll have to choose one or the other.